# How to display repeated words in an array using LiveCode

Tags: livecode

I am a beginner in LiveCode. How I display repeated words and their count in an array. Is it possible?

```
global ar

on mouseUp
    --answer ar
    //ar contain some text
    put ar into s1
    split s1 by CR
    put the number of lines of (the keys of s1) into s2
    repeat for each word k in s1
        put  s1[k] into k1 
        split k1 by CR
    end repeat
    answer k1[1]
end mouseUp

repeat for each key j in myArrayT
    put  myArrayT[j] into k 
    split k by colon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a field and fill it with a bunch of words, many of which repeat one or more times. Name that field "wordList". Now in a button script:

```
on mouseUp
   get fld "wordList"
  repeat for each word tWord in it
  add 1 to wordCount[tword]
 end repeat
 combine wordCount by return and comma
 answer wordCount
end mouseUp
```